# Beginner Java Netbeans: How do I display for loop in jlabel?

Tags: java, netbeans, for-loop, jlabel

I have looked on this site and nothing has really answered my question. This is what my code looks like:

```
    // declare user input variables
    int min, max;

    //assign user input to min and max
    min = Integer.parseInt(Min.getText ());
    max = Integer.parseInt(Max.getText ());

    //use for loop to display the values
    for (int n = min; n<= max; n++){
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(n));
        Output.setText(Integer.toString(n));
    }
```

and the System.out.println () yields the correct answer. for instance, the user inputs 2 and 9, it will say:

```
run:
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

but the jLabel I'm trying to set the text to, Output, only displays 9. I know his might be stupidly simple but hey, I'm a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah you trying to do a counter of some kind or do you want the numbers appended to the end ie `123456789`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer "depends".

Do you want each number on a new line or appended to the end of the `String`.  Do you want them displayed individually like a counter?

If you want the numbers display in sequence, then you could use something like this...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
int min = 0;
int max = 10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
for (int n = min; n <= max; n++) {
    sb.append(n);
}
label.setText(sb.toString());
```

Which will output something like...

[image: labels in a row]

Or if you wanted each number of a new line, you could use...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
int min = 0;
int max = 10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append("<html>");
for (int n = min; n <= max; n++) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(n));
    sb.append(n).append("<br>");
}
sb.append("</html>");
label.setText(sb.toString());
```

Which will output something like...

[image: labels per line]

Now, if you want this, it would actually be easier to use a `JTextArea` and simply append each number to it...

```
JTextArea editor = new JTextArea(10, 10);
editor.setEditable(false);
int min = 0;
int max = 10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
for (int n = min; n <= max; n++) {
    editor.append(Integer.toString(n) + "\n");
}
```

Which will output something like...

[image]

Now, if you want to animate it, you're going to need to do things different, either using a `javax.swing.Timer` or `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `System.out.println`, it is writing the string you give it to STDOUT (aka your terminal).  However, every time you call `Output.setText`, it is replacing the last string you set it to.

The solution would be to create a single string containing the concatenation of all the individual numbers and then send that string into `Output.setText`.

To create a string in a loop in Java you could do

```
// Create string "0\n1\n2\n3..."
String s = "";
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    s += i + "\n";
}
```

Alternatively, there is a class built into Java called `StringBuilder` which is preferred in situations where efficiency is a concern.  Using `+` is very wasteful because it creates lots of intermediate objects that must be garbage collected.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    s.append(i);
    s.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: Good point! I suppose `<br>` should be used as you suggested in your own post!

Comment: I had to test it (`\n`) to make sure first ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
String nums = "";

for (..........) {
    nums += yourResult + " ";  // this will give a space separating your output
}

label.setText(nums);
```

Keep adding to the String every iteration, then just set the final text to the label.

Comment: `JLabel` doesn't support (or more to the point, render) new line characters. It's also not advisable to do `String` concatenation within a loop, it's generally recommended to use `StringBuilder`, but given the number of loops we're talking about, that's more of a nit pick

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd normally do:

```
String vals = "";
int min = Integer.parseInt(Min.getText ());
int max = Integer.parseInt(Max.getText ());

for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    vals = vals + Integer.toString(i) + " ";

output.setText(vals);
```